# net core ef multiple relationship between entites

Tags: c#, entity-framework, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I have some trouble i have Route entites which have two properties Node StartNode 
and the second Node StartNode.
The start node and end node should should have relation with Route but when i try this i got the exception: `Cannot create a relationship between 'Node.Route' and 'Route.EndNode', because there already is a relationship between 'Node.Route' and 'Route.StartNode'. Navigation properties can only participate in a single
relationship.`

The route entites have two object Node represent start point and end point:

```
public class Route
{
    public Guid DailyRouteId { get; set; }
    public DailyRoute DailyRoute { get; set; }
    public Node StartNode { get; protected set; }
    public Node EndNode { get; protected set; }
    public Guid EndNodeId { get; set; }
    public Guid StartNodeId { get; set; }
}
```

The Node entites :

```
public class Node
{
    [Key]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; protected set; }
    public double Longitude { get; protected set; }
    public double Latitude { get; protected set; }
    public DateTime UpdatedAt { get; protected set; }

    public Route Route { get; set; }
}
```

And this is the modelbuilder:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Route>()
            .HasOne(x => x.StartNode)
            .WithOne(x => x.Route)
            .HasForeignKey<Route>(x => x.StartNodeId)
            .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict);

        modelBuilder.Entity<Route>()
            .HasOne(x => x.EndNode)
            .WithOne(x => x.Route)
            .HasForeignKey<Route>(x => x.EndNodeId)
            .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a navigation property for each relationship:

```
public class Node
{
    [Key]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; protected set; }
    public double Longitude { get; protected set; }
    public double Latitude { get; protected set; }
    public DateTime UpdatedAt { get; protected set; }

    public Route StartRoute { get; set; }
    public Route EndRoute { get; set; }
}

modelBuilder.Entity<Route>()
        .HasOne(x => x.StartNode)
        .WithOne(x => x.StartRoute)
        .HasForeignKey<Route>(x => x.StartNodeId)
        .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict);

    modelBuilder.Entity<Route>()
        .HasOne(x => x.EndNode)
        .WithOne(x => x.EndRoute)
        .HasForeignKey<Route>(x => x.EndNodeId)
        .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict);
```

Comment: but one route should have two node start and end the node represent coordinate

Comment: A start node and an end node right? You've defined it as a one-to-one relationship in your modelBuilder so I'm only going off your code. To get around the error you are receiving you need a navigation property for each foreign key relationship you are defining - one to start Route and one to end Route.